# Drop down options doesn't moves with the select box

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, default

I have a div with some content that gets hide after 5 seconds but below it, I have a drop-down with some options. So what happens when the select box is open and at the same time the div gets hidden, the options box remains in the same place and doesn't shift upwards with the select box.

Creating a custom drop-down is not an option. As well as making the above div absolute or fixed. Making the drop-down blur is also not an option. Can someone tell me if this default behaviour can be somehow changed?

1. The client does not agree for a custom solution.
2. The client does not want the above div to float or position absolute or fixed. He wants the same setup but this thing fixed.
3. Closing the select box or using blur() is also not that the client wants.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <body>
   <div class='war'>SOME RANDOM CODE which gets hidden after 5 seconds. Make sure to open the drop down</div>
   <select>
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="opel">Opel</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
   </select>
   <script>
   setTimeout(function(){ $(".war").hide(); }, 3000);
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: You may have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your question making sure anyone possibly can help you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this workaround:

- When the select menu is clicked, it gets a size attribute that is as big as all its containing option elements so that it moves with the element in the window, as it disappears.
- If you add some css styling it does not become apparent to the user that the size of the selection element has changed while he/she is in the process of selecting an option.
- Unfortunately the standard arrow styling is different, depending on the browser. My solution looks best in chrome but not optimal in firefox for example - so further browser specific optimization should be added.

Here is the corresponding code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>example</title>
<style>
  #box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  
  #options {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  #first::after {
  content: "  ⯆ ";
  font-size: 10px;
  }

  </style>
  </head>
<body>
<div id="box"></div>
  <select name="selectionarea" id="options" onclick="makeBoxDisappear();expandSelect()" onfocusout="minimizeSelect()">
    <option value="option1" id="first">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option>
    <option value="option5">option5</option>    
  </select>
  <script>
  
  function makeBoxDisappear() {
    setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none", 1000);
  }

  
  function expandSelect() {
    document.getElementById("options").size="5";
  }


  function minimizeSelect() {
    document.getElementById("options").size="1";
  }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```